# Vue Router history mode with Express and nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, vue-router

I have configured nginx to pass all requests to Node:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.tld;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

On the server I have a Node app running Express which servers my Vue index file.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/app/index.html`);
});
```

I want to use HTML5 history mode with Vue router, so I set `mode: 'history'` in the router settings. I installed [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) and set it up:

```
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
app.use(history());
```

The routes works fine if the user first hits `http://domain.tld`. But, if a subroute is accessed directly, or the page is refreshed, I get a not found error.

How do I change my configuration?

Comment: Is it wise to use a node app to serve the file? Wouldn't it be better to use e.g. nginx in terms of resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I couldn't get the connect-history-api-fallback library working, I created one myself:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.originalUrl.includes('/dist/', 0)) {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/app/index.html`);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

This will send the `/app/index.html` when requested anything but `/dist` where scripts and images are located.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

It won't work when the order is:

```
app.use(express.static('web'));
app.use(history());
```

,but will work when:

```
app.use(history());
app.use(express.static('web'));
```

Whole example app:

```
var express = require('express');
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
var app = express();

app.use(history());
app.use(express.static('web'));

app.listen(3002, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3002!')
});
```

In **web folder** i have:
index.html
and other js, css files.

Comment: Don't understand how your answer has not picket as the correct one. This fixed it for me and I can now use the package

Comment: Yes this! This fixed it for me, artuu can you explain why swapping history/static fixes it?